# Jquery show/hide hover or mouse enter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so im trying to get some text that is hidden to display when the mouse enters the div then hide when it leaves

so far ive got this on my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nannen05/5PR5E/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".image").mouseover(function(){
 $(".hover").show();
 })
$(".image").mouseout(function(){
 $(".hover").hide();
});
```

Thanks any help would be great

Comment: Check your fiddle you haven't include js

Comment: You have some missmatch tags in your html

Comment: You didn't include jQuery and had some syntax errors, here http://jsfiddle.net/5PR5E/1/

Comment: Thank you now what if i wanted to say add a red car and when hovered over it says red car too

Answer (score 0):

You Should Read Basic of **JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".image").mouseover(function(){
  $(".hover").show();
  })
    $(".image").mouseout(function(){
  $(".hover").hide();
});
})//added
```

<kbd>[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/5PR5E/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a `});`

Also, you can simplify your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image").mouseover(function () {
        $(".hover").show();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(".hover").hide();
    });
});
```

BTW, your HTML is broken. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Both your HTML and JS code are badly written. And you didn't include jQuery is your jsfiddle, which means that '$' isn't recognized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image").mouseover(function(){
      $(".hover").show();
  });
  $(".image").mouseout(function(){
      $(".hover").hide();
  });
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5PR5E/3/